# -Inf is converted into #NAME?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to display the string "-Inf" in a cell in Excel (Microsoft Office Standard 2010).

However, the cell displays the string "#NAME?" instead.

How can I alleviate this?

I have set the type of all cells to "text - Text format cells are treated as text even when a number is entered in the cell. The cell is displayed exactly as entered", so I am a bit surprised that it doesn't actually display the text exactly as entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Excel is interpreting that as a formula. Try prepending an apostrophe, to force Excel to treat it as plain text:

```
'-Inf
```